# Derived class attributes

Tags: python

```
Class A(): 
    x=0 

class B(A): 
    b=1
```

1-`print(B.__dict__)` # no x attribute in B.**dict**

```
if B.x==0:
    B.x=1
```

2-`print(B.__dict__)` # there is x attribute in B.**dict**
 Why the output is different in 1 and 2?

Comment: Can you improve the formatting of your question. Its difficult to grasp what you are asking.

Comment: Because `x` belongs to `A`. Note, `B` has *access* to the `A` namespace, since it inherits from `A`, but that doesn't mean that the two namespaces are equivalent. `B` has an `x` attribute in your second example **because you gave an `x` attribute to `B`**: i.e. `B.x=1`

Comment: This is why the MRO should probably be called the ARO.

Comment: @wim yeah that would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Because `x` belongs to `A`. Note, `B` has access to the `A` namespace, since it inherits from `A`, but that doesn't mean that the two namespaces are equivalent. `B` has an `x` attribute in your second example because you gave an `x` attribute to `B`: i.e. `B.x=1`

It is important to familiarize yourself with the [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy). Note, in the standard type hierachy under "custom classes" there is some highly relevant information:

> Custom class types are typically created by class definitions (see
>   section Class definitions). A class has a namespace implemented by a
>   dictionary object. Class attribute references are translated to
>   lookups in this dictionary, e.g., `C.x` is translated to
>   `C.__dict__["x"]` (although there are a number of hooks which allow
>   for other means of locating attributes). **When the attribute name is
>   not found there, the attribute search continues in the base classes.**
>   This search of the base classes uses the C3 method resolution order
>   which behaves correctly even in the presence of ‘diamond’ inheritance
>   structures where there are multiple inheritance paths leading back to
>   a common ancestor. Additional details on the C3 MRO used by Python can
>   be found in the documentation accompanying the 2.3 release at
>   https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/.
>
> ...
>
> **Class attribute assignments update the class’s dictionary, never the dictionary of a base class.**